Create a GitHub personal access token via cli?
I am searching for a way to create a GitHub personal access token (PAT) via the terminal.
I looked at Terraform, but the Terraform provider for GitHub does not offer any resources to create a PAT.
Also the GitHub CLI gh seems not to offer any possibility to create a PAT.
Is the only way to create a PAT via the web interface of GitHub?

Try using a third party tool - github-personal-access-token-generator-cli

https://github.com/jaebradley/github-personal-access-token-generator-cli shows at least that it is doable ;)

as mentioned in this post, it is currently not possible to generate a GitHub PAT through the CLI. More about PAT creation and management can be found in the official docs.
